# Adding a element in dictionary which consist of dictionaries.

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which consist of lists. Now how will it be possible to add a variable/element in the list for the example provided below.

```
inventory = {
    'gold': 20,
    'bag': ['chocolate', 'chips', 'food'] 
}
```

Now how do I add something in the list bag.

I have already tried this but it does not work.

```
inventory.bag.append('test')
inventory.bag.insert('test')
```

Comment: I've extensively fixed your Python syntax to at least make *some* sense and work up to the point where what you tried won't work but at least be accepted as syntactically correct. Please in future at least produce something that can be run in a Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [*subscription*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions), so `object[...]`, to address elements in the dictionary:

```
inventory['bag'].append('test')
```

Here `inventory['bag']` retrieves the value associated with the `'bag'` key. This is a list object, so you can then call the `append()` method on that result.

Answer (score 1):

You need access dict value like inventory['bag'], then because the value is a list, you just need call append method

```
inventory['bag'].append('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo of How to Append and Insert element in the list.

List `append()` method will add given element at the last.

```
>>> l1 = [11, 12, 13]
>>> l1.append(20)
>>> l1
[11, 12, 13, 20]
#             ^
```

List `insert()` method will take two arguments, First is index where you want to insert given element and second is element which need to insert.

```
>>> l1.insert(1, 22)
>>> l1
[11, 22, 12, 13, 20]
#     ^
```

---

Consider `dictionary` where `key` i.e.number have `value` as `List Object`.

```
>>> d = {"number":[11, 12]}
>>> d["number"]
[11, 12]
>>> d["number"].append(22)
>>> d
{'number': [11, 12, 22]}
>>> d["number"].insert(2, 20)
>>> d["number"]
[11, 12, 20, 22]
>>>
```